# Security Authorization by Authority doesn't work correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have Controller, that must update information about My Course in html page. If i login like admin i can update information about Instructor and about Course, if i login like Instructor i can update information only about my Course.
I use xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security + need dependency for hiding information that can see only admin, and info that must see only instructor. But when i run application and login like admin or like instructor i see both part information without hiding.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping ("/update")
    @PreAuthorize ("hasAnyAuthority ('Admin','Instructor')")
    public String updateCourse (Model model, Long courseId, Principal principal) {
    if (userService.doesUserHasRole("Instructor")) {
        Instructor instructor = instructorService.loadInstrucotrByEmail(principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("currentInstructor", instructor);
    }
        Course course = courseService.loadCourseBycourseId(courseId);
        List <Instructor> instructors = instructorService.fetchInstrucotr();
        model.addAttribute("course", course);
        model.addAttribute("listInstructor", instructors);
        return "course/update";
    }
```

Part of my code in update.html page, where i have problem

```
            <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                <label class="form-label"> Instructor: </label>
                <select sec:authorize="hasAuthority('Admin')" th:field="${course.instructor}" name="instructor"
                    class="form-select">
                    <option th:each="instructor:${listInstructor}"
                        th:text="${instructor.getFirstName()} + ' ' +${instructor.getLastName()}"
                        th:value="${instructor.getInstructorId()}"></option>
                </select> **see that view, when i login like Instructor!**
                
                <select sec:authorize="!hasAuthority ('Admin') && hasAuthority('Instructor')" th:field="${course.instructor}" name="instructor"
                    class="form-select">
                    <option selected th:each="instructor:${currentInstructor}"
                        th:text="${instructor.getFirstName()} + ' ' +${instructor.getLastName()}"
                        th:value="${instructor.getInstructorId()}"></option>
                </select>
                
            </div>
```

Also picture how that look

[image]

I check dependency, everything good, and try to add sec:authorize="!hasAuthority ('Instructor') && hasAuthority('Admin')" instead of sec:authorize="hasAuthority ('Admin'), but id did not work.

If you know where problem, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends how you have implemented your roles / authorities.

If I were you, I will try to dive inside the current authenticated user to get your current roles and authorities. You will see where the problem is as fast as a thunder in the night's sky.